# ProgressBar without value, just loading

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

What do I need to do to create a progress bar like this using WinForms?

[image: Progressbar]

Comment: (I've changed the question radically to how I interpret the question. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12603195/revisions)  is the original version.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's called a marquee progress bar.  Just use a regular `ProgressBar` and set:

```
myProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```

and

```
myProgressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = yourDesiredSpeed;
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly set the speed.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a classic ProgressBar Control and specify :

```
myProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```

Comment: This requires to have visual styles enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [style property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style.aspx) - Set it to `Marquee`. [MSDN link on styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle.aspx)